# Kaggle notebook is not able to read the dataset

Tags: python, kaggle

I'm trying to read a CSV file at kaggle platform, but I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'../input/Salaries.csv' does not exist: b'../input/Salaries.csv'
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
sal = pd.read_csv('../input/Salaries.csv')
```

I can see the input window on the notebook's right side and the path and the file name matches the code.

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:-

```
import os
print(os.listdir("../input"))
```

It shows you what files you have available, which you can then copy-and-paste to the appropriate path.

Comment: It showed an existing subfolder that is not being displayed to me. After that, I could set the correct path. Tks.

Comment: @Filipe If this answer is useful, Can you upvote it?

Comment: Nice answer Karul.